# ionic2 hacer una consulta a una api cuando el view carga

Tags: nodejs, ionic, api, angularjs-2.0

Quiero hacer la consulta a una api xxxxxx/yyy , apenas carga un view ,el problema esta que cuando la página carga no recibo una respuesta.

Este es mi código.

ejemplo.ts

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {

    this.chats.push("Hola prueba del chat");
    this.asistenteProvider.chat("Hola")
    .subscribe(res=>{
        console.log("Respuesta enviando mensajex2",res);
        this.chats.push(res);
    },error=>{
        console.log("error",error);
    });

  }
```

Mi provider

Ejemplo.provider.ts

```
export class EjemploProvider {
    url:string;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.url="/chat";
    console.log('Hello');
  }

  chat(mensaje:string){
    console.log("Mensaje a enviar",mensaje);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

    return  this.http.post(
            this.url,
            {
                data:mensaje
            },
            options
            ).map(response=>{
                return response.json();
            }
            )

}
}
```

**Cuando la vista carga viendo la consola aparecen los mensajes , pero no el estado si se ha recibido o rechazado el request.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cuando envio el primer mensaje  me sale un error y no recibo respuesta**

[image: Cuando envio el primer mensaje me sale un error y no recibo respuesta]

**Cuando envio mas mensajes a partir del 2° la respuesta me salen todavia errores pero la respuesta si se da**

[image: Cuando envio mas mensajes a partir del 2° la respuesta me salen todavia errores pero la respuesta si se da]

Luego cuando envió mensajes ya no me salen errores y recibo la respuesta correctamente.

Estoy usando un proxy para poder hacer la consulta a la api , pues esta no tiene activada cors.
¿A que se debe?.

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema debe estar en los links (ubicación) a los que se le hace la solicitud al **API**, verifica en tu navegador si están disponibles y sí está permitido hacer **POST** al mismo.